# how to make an object bounce off the walls?

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a game in which the happy face object will bounce off of all the walls continuously. Each time it bounces off a wall the colour will be randomly changed. As of right now, my happyFace object is changing colour continuously but it's not bouncing from wall to wall but instead changing colour on the same spot. How would I be able to change the code for it to start bouncing off the wall instead of staying in one place??

```
# import the necessary modules
import pygame
import sys
import math
import random

# initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# set the size for the surface (screen)
# note this screen is resizable by the user
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.RESIZABLE)
# set the caption for the screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Happy Face")

#screen width and height
screenW = screen.get_width()
screenH = screen.get_height()

# define colours you will be using
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

color = GREEN 
color2 = BLUE
color3 = RED

# funtion to draw a the "happy face"
# it has 4 parameters passed to it xPos, yPos, radius, and colour
# notice all the shapes are drawn "relative" to the xPos and yPos and the radius
def drawHappy(xPos,yPos,r,color):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,color,(xPos,yPos),r,1)
    eyeRadius = int(1/6*r)
    eyeX = int(xPos-1/3*r)
    eyeY = int(yPos- 1/3*r)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,color,(eyeX,eyeY),eyeRadius,1)
    eyeX = int(xPos + 1/3*r)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,color,(eyeX,eyeY),eyeRadius,1)
    wMouth = 1.5*r
    xMouth = xPos - 3/4*r
    yMouth = yPos - 3/4*r
    pygame.draw.arc(screen,color,(xMouth,yMouth,wMouth,wMouth),math.pi,2*math.pi,1)

def random_color():
    random_number = random.randint(1,3)
    if random_number == 1:
            return GREEN
    elif random_number ==2:
            return BLUE
    else:
            return RED

# set up clock to control frames per second
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 120

go = True

while go: # loop to randomize colour as it touches the side of the screen
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        go = False
xPos = 0
yPos = 0
dx = 0
dy = 0

xPos2 = 0
yPos2 = 0
dx2 = 0
dy2 = 0

xPos3 = 0
yPos3 = 0 
dx3 = 0
dy3 = 0

xPos = xPos + dx
yPos = yPos + dy

yPos2 = yPos2 + dy2
xPos2 = xPos2 + dx2

yPos3 = yPos3 + dy3
xPos3 = xPos3 + dx3


# set main loop to True so it will run
main = True
# main loop
while main:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # check for any events (i.e key press, mouse click etc.)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # check to see if it was "x" at top right of screen
            main = False # set the "main" variable to False to exit while loop

        if xPos >= 750:
            dxPos = -abs(dx)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_color())
            color = random_color()
        elif xPos <=50:
            dx = abs(dx)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_color())
            color = random_color()

        if yPos <= 50:
            dy = abs(dy)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_color())
            color = random_color()
        elif yPos >=550:
            dyPos = -abs(dyPos)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_color())
            color = random_color()

        if xPos2 >= 775:
            dx = -abs(dx)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_color())
            color2 = random_color()
        elif xPos2 <= 25:
            dx = abs(dx)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_color())
            color2 = random_color()

        if   yPos2 <= 25:
            dy = abs(dy)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_color())
            color2 = random_color()
        elif yPos2 >= 575:
            dy = -abs(dy)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_color())
            color2 = random_color()

        if   xPos3 >=700:
            dx = -abs(dx)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_color())
            color3 = random_color()
        elif xPos3 <= 100:
            dx = abs(dx)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_color())
            color3 = random_color()

        if   yPos3 <= 100:
            dy = abs(dy)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_color())
            color3 = random_color()
        elif yPos3 >= 500:
            dy = -abs(dy)
            shape = drawHappy(xPos, yPos, 1, random_color())
            color3 = random_color()


    clock.tick(FPS)
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # "call" the function "drawHappy()" to draw the happy face
    # this is where we would normally do a pygame.draw or a screen.blit()
    # we are "passing" the function 4 values to use(x,y,radius, colour)
    # it will use these to know where to draw the happy face
    drawHappy(300,300,200,random_color())

    pygame.display.flip()

# quit pygame and exit the program (i.e. close everything down)
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

General observations about your code:

- More than one event-loop (bad)
- No clear entry-point. The order of execution is not easy to follow
  since everything sits in the global scope
- Repeated code due to lack of object-oriented programming
- Magic numbers/literals baked into the source code which makes making
  changes difficult
- The comments are not useful

Specific observations:

Anytime you call `drawHappy`, you are also calling `random_color` to get a new random color. Since you are calling these two functions every frame, your happy faces will change color every frame.

Here are my suggestions:

- Create a `HappyFace` class. An instance of this class represents one
  happy face. Each instance of this class has its own position,
  velocity and color. You can even change any given instance's radius
  or line thickness if you want to.
- Move things out of the global scope. Define an obvious entry-point
  for your program - I'm using `main`.
- Only use one event-loop

I've never used pygame, so I don't know what the standard solution for a proper pygame game-loop looks like (where you're updating the game state and rendering the game at different rates).

Code:

```
import pygame

def get_random_color():
    from random import randint
    return tuple(randint(0, 255) for _ in range(3))


class HappyFace:

    def __init__(self):
        from random import randint, choice, uniform

        self.radius = 25
        self.eye_radius = self.radius / 6

        self.x = randint(self.radius + 1, HappyFace.screen.get_width() - self.radius - 1)
        self.y = randint(self.radius + 1, HappyFace.screen.get_height() - self.radius - 1)
        self.dx = choice([-1, 1]) * uniform(0.01, 0.05)
        self.dy = choice([-1, 1]) * uniform(0.01, 0.05)

        self.color = get_random_color()
        self.line_thickness = 1

    def draw(self):
        from math import pi
        x = int(self.x)
        y = int(self.y)
        pygame.draw.circle(HappyFace.screen, self.color, (x, y), self.radius, self.line_thickness)
        pygame.draw.circle(HappyFace.screen, self.color, (x - self.radius // 3, y - self.radius // 3), self.radius // 6, self.line_thickness)
        pygame.draw.circle(HappyFace.screen, self.color, (x + self.radius // 3, y - self.radius // 3), self.radius // 6, self.line_thickness)
        pygame.draw.arc(HappyFace.screen, self.color, (x - self.radius // 4 * 3, y - self.radius // 4 * 3, int(self.radius * 1.5), int(self.radius * 1.5)), pi, pi * 2, self.line_thickness)

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.dy

        if self.x - self.radius <= 0 or self.x + self.radius >= HappyFace.screen.get_width():
            self.dx *= -1
            self.color = get_random_color()
        if self.y - self.radius <= 0 or self.y + self.radius >= HappyFace.screen.get_height():
            self.dy *= -1
            self.color = get_random_color()


def main():

    screen_width, screen_height = 400, 400

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Window")

    HappyFace.screen = screen

    number_of_faces = 5
    faces = [HappyFace() for _ in range(number_of_faces)]

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                break
        else:
            screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
            for face in faces:
                face.draw()
                face.update()
            pygame.display.flip()
            continue
        break

    pygame.display.quit()
    pygame.quit()
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```